# Can AppleScript listen for events?

Tags: events, event-handling, applescript, hook, listener

I want to write a script that takes action when a document is opened on a certain application, or before an application quits, etc.

Is there a way to attach a script to an event in an application? Does AppleScript support any form of hooks at all?

If not, can I hack my way into getting what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

applescript only has certain "event listeners" the are folder action script that might be considered an event listener and indesign has real event listeners which I won't get into at the moment.

if you want a blanket listener for any application to quit you may find what your looking for in a [Quickeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) though I'm not certain of this as it has been a long time since I have messed around with quickeys.

but all and all the answer is for the most part no.

hth
Mike

**EDIT** *more tools that may help brought by [kch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13989/kch)*

[FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)

[QuickSilver](http://quicksilver.en.softonic.com/mac)

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

"Some apps, eg. iChat, have script hooks in the preferences. In iChat, the Alerts preference pane, you can set it to run a script when a certain event is triggered, like message received, file transfer request, etc." – kch

Comment: Add to the list of tools that more or less help with this: FastScripts, Quicksilver, Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: Some apps, eg. iChat, have script hooks in the preferences. In iChat, the Alerts preference pane, you can set it to run a script when a certain event is triggered, like message received, file transfer request, etc.

Comment: Ok I'll go ahead and accept your answer. It would be nice if you incorporated my comments in it for completion.